# New SSL Certificate for new website domain

Tags: web-services, ssl, https

I'm replacing a current https webservice.

The webservice and clients have the current SSL certificate. The cert was issue to **example.test.local**, which correlates to the domain of the web service:

***https:\example.test.local:4434\test\example.svc***

I'm replace the current web service and domain address it uses:

https:\example1.test.local:4434\test\example2.svc

Can I reuse the original SSL certificate with my new web service URL?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your certificate is not issued for the new domain `example1.test.local`, then you can't use it. Client apps won't trust it and show a warning about wrong domain to users.

You need a new certificate.